# Xamarin iOS Compatibility Issues with latest Xcode 15

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac, xcode15, ios17

I am currently testing the compatibility of my iOS applications developed using Xamarin iOS. However, I'm encountering problems with both Xcode 15 beta and Visual Studio 2022 (version 17.6) on my MacBook.

Specifically, I am facing pairing issues with both IDEs, as no iOS simulators are available for debugging and I am unable to open storyboards, among other issues.

I would like to know if Xcode 15 beta and Visual Studio 2022 (version 17.6) are compatible with Xamarin iOS development, or if I need to wait for a future release of Visual Studio for Mac. Any insights or guidance on resolving these compatibility issues would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I just installed the Xcode 15 beta and enabled the beta updates for my iPhone 11... Xamarin.Forms didn't like that...

I'm facing the following errors:

```
/Users/*****/******/******/******.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT4109: Failed to compile the generated registrar code. Please file a bug report at https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/new (MT4109) (******.iOS)
```

After some research, I found the following:
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/18409#issuecomment-1599201944

**The solution of my project:**

1. I've installed the Xcode beta
2. I've installed the [xamarin.ios-16.4.0.18.pkg](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/de7f727f-243c-4429-8773-eebd735eb1bb/da4a65f27ace7f805914ef63661e0efd/xamarin.ios-16.4.0.18.pkg)
3. Enabled the beta updates on iPhone 11 and installed the iOS 17
4. Add `--weak-framework=NewsstandKit.framework/NewsstandKit` on Xamarin.iOS project properties>iOS>Build>Additional arguments

I really hope the above steps help you with your problem!!

Comment: in visual studio mac, I see the latest Xamarin.ios version available is 16.4.0.6

Comment: @RaGibNoor You can see this issue on github [link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/18964)

However, installing this version of xamarin-ios will let you build the app on iOS17 using XCode 15 but (in my case) Apple review rejected my archived build.

Comment: what was the rejection reason from Apple?

Comment: ITMS-90424: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is empty. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.

Comment: Hi, i do have to follow the steps but still getting the error. 
can you confirm which ios sdk version you are using?

Comment: I've used the xamarin.ios 16.4.0.18 on VS4Mac the links in my answer are correct. You can download and install the xamarin iOS. Ensure that you are using the XCode 15 on your visual studio on VisualStudio>Preferences>SDK Locations>Apple.  I don't know if my scenario is applicable new that both XCode15 and iOS 17 are officially released. What is your error ?

Answer (score 0):

Just after in installing  xamarin.ios-16.4.0.18.pkg. simulators started showing. able to build and debug on simulators.

Comment: How to install xamarin.ios-16.4.0.18.pkg ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to deploy to simulators, but the ability to use physical devices is not officially supported (and doesn't work currently).

You also can't debug your iOS 17 device when using Xcode 14.x. The issue seems to be related to the developer tools that get installed with Xcode 15 on the iOS 17 device. Those tools seem to be incompatible with the ones on Xcode 14.

This is a big issue because some things can't be done on a simulator properly.